# node:10212[DEP0123]DeprecationWarning:Setting the TLS ServerName to an IPaddress is not permitted by RFC 6066.This will be ignored in a future version

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Below is my nodejs code to connect to a mssql database and query data

```
const sql = require('mssql')
export class GetJDBCCasedata {
  async fetchData(wellid, wellboreid, designid) {
    var result
     console.log("In fetchdata")
const sqlConfig = {
  user: 'root',
  password:'root',
  database: 'student',
  server: '12.11.234.12',
 /* pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  },*/
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
  }
}
console.log("CONFIG FOR SERVER "+JSON.stringify(sqlConfig))
 try {
  console.log("Connecting to database")
  result=await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
  console.log("Connected to database")
 } catch (err) {
  result=err
  console.log("ERROR OCCURRED "+err)
 }
return result
  }
}
```

The code runs fine and I get the message as "Connected to database". However I get a message as "(node:10212) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version." What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Don't use an IP address from the server name; the error is telling you that.

Comment: How else do I point out to that server?

Comment: Use the Server Name instead.

Comment: I have executed SELECT @@SERVERNAME to get servername,when I used the result I got connection error

Comment: That would suggest that the device you are using the connect can't resolve the hostname, @riya .

Comment: In that case should I ignore this warning?

Comment: I find this warning inane! Justification: you are given an ip to connect to (There is no DNS for this ip, it is a local network.) Even if you do an nslookup, you get the router name - THESE CAN'T BE USED. This error enforces an additional name translation dependency - as I stated - INANE

Answer (score 23):

I solved same issue by encrypt:false.

```
options: {
encrypt: false,
trustServerCertificate: true,
}
```

Comment: Isn't `trustServerCertificate` redundant if encryption is disabled? If there is no encryption, there are no certificates involved in the process either I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use the value received from
`SELECT @@SERVERNAME`
and I link that up to the IP of the server via the windows hosts file it works and drops the warning.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an extra local box e.g. a virtual machine. A simple way of mapping an ip to a domain name (for the above op's type of usage) is through your hosts file.

Reference Jarmund - it was his solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1113845/how-to-give-a-domain-name-to-a-local-ip

Also reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system
to find where your hosts file is for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the sftp address with case sensitive on how the DNS was created.
we ran into issue when we used the lower case
when we changed it to upper case Lambda worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Make options encrypt like this `encrypt: false`:

```
options: { 
   encrypt: false, 
   trustServerCertificate: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that this is fine in your situation. Let's look at the documentation of this deprecation:

https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0123

The wording there is the same as the error message but what's interesting is the link deep into the RFC in question, directly to the section on "Server Name Indication"

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066#section-3

Server Name Indication is about when more than one domain is hosted at an ip address and so the connecting client needs to tell the server which of its domains it wants to connect to. This is so the server can bring out the right certs chain etc for that domain, since each will be different.

So I think what's talked about being ignored here is the identification of the domain you're trying to talk to, when you try to identify it using a numeric address. If you are running a single service over HTTPS at the IP address, without any per-domain differentiation to be done, this is fine.

If you really are wanting to serve multiple domains at an IP address, you will need to use a real DNS entry or some name you make up to put in your /etc/hosts, and configure your HTTPS server with those multiple domain names, and not with a numeric address as identifying the server name in this way will not work.

Answer (score 0):

100% fix

```
options: {
   encrypt: false,
   trustServerCertificate: true,
   enableArithAbort: true
}
```

Answer (score -6):

100% Working..!!

```
options: {
  encrypt: true,
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.